Typo in Lee's Smooth manifold Theorem 6.30?
The theorem is the statement about transversality; the important bit of the theorem is the statement:

Let $F:N\rightarrow M$ be a smooth map transverse to an embedded submanifold $S\subset M$. Then $F^{-1}(S)$ is a smooth manifold.

In the proof, the bit I have an issue with is the following:

Let $m$ be the dimension of $M$, and $k$ be the codimension of $S$. Given $x\in F^{-1}(S)$, we can find a neighborhood $U$ of $F(x)$ in M and a local
defining function $\phi: U\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$, with $S\cap U=\phi^{-1}(0)$. The theorem will be
proved if we can show that $0$ is a regular value of $\phi\circ F$ , because $F^{-1}(S)\cap F^{-1}(U)$ is the zero set of $\phi\circ F|_{F^{-1}(U)}$

My issue is why is the theorem proved after we show that $0$ is a regular value of $\phi\circ F$? Don't we need to actually show that $\phi\circ F|_{F^{-1}(U)}$ is a submersion? Because the theorem seems to be using proposition $5.16$ from Lee's smooth manifolds which states that:

Let S be a subset of a smooth $m$-manifold $M$. Then $S$ is an embedded $k$ submanifold if and only if every point in $S$ has a neighborhood $U\subset M$ such that $U\cap S$ is the level set of a smooth submersion $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb R^{m-k}$.

Are these equivalent somehow? I know we can take the level set to be $\phi^{-1}(0)$, but is there any reason that if $0$ is a regular value that $\phi$ should be a submersion? Or in the case that is actually important, is there any reason that if $0$ is a regular value of $\phi\circ F|_{F^{-1}(U)}$ that $\phi\circ F|_{F^{-1}(U)}$ is a smooth submersion?

Let $X,Y$ be smooth manifolds and $f:X\to Y$ a smooth map. In general, having a point $y\in Y$ which is a regular-value of $f$ does not imply $f$ is a submersion.

For a trivial counterexample, consider the case where $f$ is a non-surjective map which is not a submersion; then every point not in the image of $f$ is (vacuously) a regular value.
For a non-vacuous counterexample, consider $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x^2-x$. Then, $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0,1\}$, but $f’(x)=2x-1$ is such that $f’(0)=-1$ and $f’(1)=1$ are both non-zero, i.e $0$ is a regular-value of $f$. However, $f$ is not a submersion because $f’(1/2)=0$, i.e $f$ doesn’t have full rank at $\frac{1}{2}$.

However, this isn’t really an issue here because if $y\in Y$ is a regular-value of $f:X\to Y$, then for each $x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$, there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f|_V$ is a submersion. This is simply because of the fact that (the tangent map of) $f$ has full rank at $x$, and since the rank locally cannot decrease, it follows there is a neighbourhood on which the rank is full.
Now, let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold, fix an integer $k\in \{0,\dots, n\}$, and a subset $S\subset M$. Then, the following statements are equivalent:

for each point $p\in S$, there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ in $M$ and a smooth submersion $\pi:V\to \Bbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that $S\cap V=\pi^{-1}(\{0\})$.
for each $p\in S$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ and a smooth function $\phi:U\to\Bbb{R}^{n-k}$ having $0$ as a regular value and such that $S\cap U=\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$.

The first bullet point obviously implies the second. To prove the converse, note that given $p\in S$ and $\phi:U\to\Bbb{R}^{n-k}$ as in the statement, we can apply our previous remark to say that there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ in $U$ (and hence open in $M$) such that $\pi:=\phi|_V$ is a submersion. Now, observe that $\pi^{-1}(\{0\})=\phi^{-1}(\{0\})\cap V=(S\cap U)\cap V=S\cap V$, since $V\subset U$. Hence, both statements are equivalent.
So, the underlying fact here is that checking whether something is a submanifold is a local thing, and also locally rank doesn’t decrease.

You can actually see this idea being implemented throughout the chapter. Look again at the proofs of Theorem 5.12 (constant-rank level set theorem) and Corollary 5.14 (regular level set theorem).

This is great thank you!
